# List within Model not reflected in View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model

I'll start by showing you what I have so far...

**Project.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ProtoSim.Models {
    public class Project {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public List<string> Images { get; set; }
        public List<string> ImageDescriptions { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime RemovedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime RestoredDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Context.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using ProtoSim.Models;

namespace ProtoSim {
    public class Context : DbContext {
        public Context () {
            Database.SetInitializer (new DatabaseInitializer ());
        }

        public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**DatabaseInitializer.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using ProtoSim.Models;

namespace ProtoSim {
    internal class DatabaseInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Context> {
        protected override void Seed (Context context) {
            context.Projects.Add (new Project () {
                Name = "ProtoSim Website",
                Description = "Website for ProtoSim business",
                Status = "In Progress",
                Image = "",
                CreatedDate = DateTime.Today,
                UpdatedDate = DateTime.Today,
                RemovedDate = DateTime.Today,
                RestoredDate = DateTime.Today
            });

            context.Projects.Add (new Project () {
                Name = "Bar Tap Prop",
                Description = "Network-enabled prop designed to interface with up to 25 taps",
                Status = "In Progress",
                Image = "#",
                Images = new List<string> { "#", "#", "#", "#", "#" },
                ImageDescriptions = new List<string> { "description one", "description two", "description three", "description four", "description five" },
                CreatedDate = DateTime.Today,
                UpdatedDate = DateTime.Today,
                RemovedDate = DateTime.Today,
                RestoredDate = DateTime.Today
            });

            context.SaveChanges ();
        }
    }
}
```

**ProjectsController.cs**

```
using ProtoSim.Data;
using ProtoSim.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Net;

namespace ProtoSim.Controllers {
    public class ProjectsController : Controller {
        private Context _context = null;
        public ProjectsController () {
            _context = new Context ();
        }

        public ActionResult Details (int id) {
            Project project = _context.Projects
                .Where (i => i.Id == id)
                .SingleOrDefault ();

            if (project == null)
                return HttpNotFound ();

            return View (project);
        }
    }
}
```

**Details.cs**

```
@using ProtoSim.Models
@model ProtoSim.Models.Project

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Project Details";
}

<body>
    <p>@Model.Images[0]</p>
</body>
```

**Error**
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxqhJ.png)

Each of the code blocks pasted here have been stripped down to relevant code.

All I'm trying to do is access the individual strings within `Model.Images`. I'm not understanding why I'm having this issue. Hoping I can get some help to figure out how I can access this List from the Details view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework does not support collections of primitive types. You can either create an entity (which will be saved to a different table) or do some string processing to save your list as a string and populate the list after the entity is materialized.

for example:

```
public class Project
{
    ...
    public List<Image> Images { get; set; }
}
public class Image
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string Url{ get; set; }
}
public class MyContext:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Image> Images { get; set; }
}
```

and in your Details action:

```
public ActionResult Details (int id) {
        Project project = _context.Projects.Include(i => i.Images)
            .Where (i => i.Id == id)
            .SingleOrDefault ();

        if (project == null)
            return HttpNotFound ();

        return View (project);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It makes sense and I have implemented it. However, this code `Project project = _context.Projects.Include (i => i.Images).Where (i => i.Id == id).SingleOrDefault ();` causes an issue; specifically `i => i.Images`. I get an error saying 'Cannot convert lambda expression to type string because it is not a delegate type'. I have no idea what that's trying to tell me

Comment: use `Include("Images")`

Comment: That has solved my problem! I'm now getting the data that I need. Thank you!